# Change row property in datagridview based on string from cell, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, properties, row

I am currently working in VB.NET visual express 2013. I am using an sql Database on my back end and am programing in Windows Forms. I am trying to get some code that will search column 9 of my multiple column datagridview and search for the word "tailshelf." There will be a bunch of characters before and after this word but I need my code to recognize this string and change the background color of the entire row to orange. I have some code I am trying but it is throwing me an error that says "System.InvaliudCastException: Conversion from string to type integer is not valid." It seems like it is saying it is trying to convert an integer to a string but that column should be set up as the varchar data type. Here is my code:
 Private Sub DGVSchedule_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DGVSchedule.RowPostPaint

```
    Try

        'change row color to look for tailshelf
        If e.RowIndex < Me.DGVSchedule.RowCount - 1 Then
            Dim dgvrow As DataGridViewRow = Me.DGVSchedule.Rows(e.RowIndex)

            If dgvrow.Cells(9).ToString.Contains("Tailshelf") Then
                dgvrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
            Else
                dgvrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor() = Color.White
            End If

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is a picture of what the string i am looking for:

[image]

FINAL WORKING CODE:

```
With DGV1
        For gridrow As Integer = 0 To .RowCount - 1
            If .Rows(gridrow).Cells(9).Value.ToString.Contains("String") Then
                .Rows(gridrow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: there is an space " * Tailshelf * ", remove that

Comment: Is'nt the * a wildcard in vb.net. I am searching for the word "tailshelf" in a description that has many other characters in it, both before and after this word.

Comment: no, you are doing it wrong, if you are searching with wildcard, use String.Contains

Comment: What is the wildcard command in vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With DGVSchedule
        For gridrow As Integer = 0 To .RowCount - 1
            If .Rows(gridrow).Cells(9).Value.ToString.Contains("TAILSHELF") Then
                .Rows(gridrow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If CInt(dgvrow.Cells(9).Value.ToString) = "*Tailshelf*" Then
```

Read that line of code, your problem lies there.  You are taking dgvrow.Cells(9).Value, converting it to a string, then converting the result of that to an integer.  You are trying to then compare an integer value to "*Tailshelf*".  Likely you have the right cell index, and lets say the value in dgvrow.Cells(9) is in fact "Tailshelf."  CInt("Tailshelf") is going to fail.  Remove the integer conversion.

Comment: Yes, i checked the cell index and it was correct. I tried removed the ".value" to where it was just .tostring and it still did not work. I got this code from another post on this website. Considering I am looking for a string I will need to change this?

Comment: If dgvrow.Cells(9).Value.ToString = "*Tailshelf*" Then

Comment: dgvrow.Cells(9) is going to get you a reference to the cell at index 9, which will be a DvGridViewCell object.  You have to access the Value property of that object, cast it to a string, and compare the result with what you are searching for.

Comment: I have updated my code and it runs now but it does not change the row color, Could it have something to do with the event I have put it under? Should i put it in my form load event instead? Please check updated code.

Comment: As piyush mentions in the comments above, try `If dgvrow.Cells(9).Value.ToString.Contains("Tailshelf")` and remember that string comparisons are case sensitive.

Comment: the case sensitive aspect did not match but I have made the changes to match and the row color still does not change. Please see the picture I am about to upload into my post.

Comment: Would the fact that this dgv is many different sql tables left joined together?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, if you want to try search this word `Tailshelf` in column index 9.

```
If (dgvrow.Cells(9).ToString.Contains("Tailshelf")) Then
```

Comment: Alright i have added this line, however my code does run, it still does not change my row color, should I change my event for the dgv to something else? see edited code

Comment: try using CellFormatting event  or RowsAdded event

Comment: follow this http://kurdsprogramming.blogspot.in/2009/02/rowdatabound-for-datagridview-windows.html

Comment: I just tried using the cellformatting event and it did not work, it does not work with the rowsadded event either.